# How to run update statistics manually for informix table which is having composite indexes?

Tags: informix

Suppose there is a table with the schema shown below containing a large number of records. For better performance, I execute update statistics manually. I need to know what is the correct way to execute the update statistics command for composite indexes. How should I use medium and high depending on the situation?

```
create table "informix".table1
  (
    ip_address char(15),
    mobile_no char(10),
    name char(20)
  ) in dbs1 extent size 64 next size 32 lock mode row;



create unique index "informix".idx_table1_1 on "informix".table1
    (ip_address,name) using btree  in idxdbs;
```

For the table above, which is the best way to update statistics from the two methods below?

```
update statistics high for table table1(ip_address,name) force;
```

OR

```
update statistics medium for table table1(name) force;
update statistics high for table table1(ip_address) force;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Informix 12.10 manual suggests:

- [Using the MEDIUM mode option](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0175.htm)

  > After UPDATE STATISTICS MEDIUM has been run on a table, the query optimizer typically chooses a more efficient execution plan, compared to the same SELECT statement when only LOW mode column distribution statistics are available for the table. column.
- [Using the HIGH mode option](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0040.htm):

  > For indexed tables that already have MEDIUM mode distribution statistics available for every column, the query optimizer typically chooses more efficient execution plans after you run UPDATE STATISTICS HIGH on every column that is part of an index key.

Since both `ip_address` and `name` are part of the unique index (you should consider designating it as the primary key too), the first option — the single HIGH mode statement — is probably most appropriate.  There's no need to run the MEDIUM mode on the same columns first.

Test it — YMMV.

Comment: what if that my index defined as non unique index? Any deference with update stat or same?

Comment: The documentation shown does not distinguish between unique and duplicate (non-unique) indexes.  On the face of it, the same rules apply.  However, I should warn you that I've not got field experience with these rules and I may be missing some nuances.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having performance problems with the queries you are running? How many records does the table have? You dont have many fields but might gain a little improvement by redefining the name field as a VARCHAR instead of a CHAR and periodically rebuilding the index. Are any of the records updated, or is this a lookup table that just periodically gets new records inserted? Can you please show us the queries you run against this table, and also show us the EXPLAIN file to see the query cost and plan the query optimizer is using? You might need an index on the name and mobile_no fields if your queries are searching by those fields, and you might also benefit from creating a cluster index depending on the queries you are running. Keep in mind that new record inserts and updates are slower when you have indexes because it must also update the index table.